# How to get a bash script to return true on function key press (for use as a Sylpheed filter)

Tags: bash, fedora

I'm currently trying to make a filter rule on Sylpheed that deletes a message from server on command, and I was thinking of writing a bash script that returns true when you press something like say, F8, then use that as an argument.

Unfortunately, that appears to be harder than expected. I've tried this code so far:

```
#!/bin/sh
f8='^[[19~'
f9='^[[20~'
echo please enter the F8 function key
read -n5 key                      # Read 5 characters.
echo -n "$key" | grep "$f8"  #Check if character code detected.
if [ "$?" -eq $SUCCESS ]
then
  echo "F8 key pressed."
  return 0
fi
echo -n "$key" | grep "$f9"  #Check if character code detected.
if [ "$?" -eq $SUCCESS ]
then
  echo "F9 key pressed."
  return 0
fi
```

that I found on the net and modified a bit, but unfortunately it doesn't seem to work (using Fedora LXDE). I got the keypress data for the F8 and F9 keys via using control-v in the terminal, then pressing F8 and same for F9.

I've tried variations of it, by deleting the ^ and changing the read -n5 to read -n4, but grep still keeps saying "grep: Unmatched" etc. Can anyone help out?

Also open to anyone who can show me how to create a filter on Slypheed to delete an email from a server as an alternative solution (apparently it is possible, but I have not been able to get it to work; currently testing it on a gmail account, and any message deleted in the client is not deleted on gmail, and I can't seem to get the filter to run on flagged messages, or coloured messages, or any variation of the above that lets the user select the messages that they want to delete from the server). I cannot switch to IMAP because of client specifications.

Answer (score 0):

Found this script on the web:

```
#!/bin/bash

_key()
{
  local kp
  ESC=$'\e'
  _KEY=
  read -d '' -sn1 _KEY
  case $_KEY in
    "$ESC")
        while read -d '' -sn1 -t1 kp
        do
          _KEY=$_KEY$kp
          case $kp in
            [a-zA-NP-Z~]) break;;
          esac
        done
    ;;
  esac
  printf -v "${1:-_KEY}" "%s" "$_KEY"
}

_key x


case $x in
  $'\e[11~' | $'\e[OP') key=F1 ;;
  $'\e[12~' | $'\e[OQ') key=F2 ;;
  $'\e[13~' | $'\e[OR') key=F3 ;;
  $'\e[14~' | $'\e[OS') key=F4 ;;
  $'\e[15~') key=F5 ;;
  $'\e[16~') key=F6 ;;
  $'\e[17~') key=F7 ;;
  $'\e[18~') key=F8 ;;
  $'\e[19~') key=F9 ;;
  $'\e[20~') key=F10 ;;
  $'\e[21~') key=F11 ;;
  $'\e[22~') key=F12 ;;
  $'\e[A' ) key=UP ;;
  $'\e[B' ) key=DOWN ;;
  $'\e[C' ) key=RIGHT ;;
  $'\e[D' ) key=LEFT ;;
  ?) key=$x ;;
  *) key=??? ;;
esac

echo "You have pressed $key"
```

Answer (score 0):

I also faced this issue. One of the problem is that different non-printable keys have different amount of characters, so after some experiments I wrote the following script:

```
# Special keypress could take variable amount of characters
keypress=""
# waiting for any key press down
read -rsN1 keytap
# loop while read can read any additional character and join all of them
while [ -n "$keytap" ]; do
 keypress="${keypress}${keytap}"
 read -sN1 -t 0.01 keytap
done
```

Now you can use case to check:

```
case "$keypress" in
  $'\e[11~') echo F1;;
  $'\e[21~') echo F10;;
  $'\e[A') echo Up arrow;;
  $'\t') echo Tab key;;
  $'\e[3~') echo Del key;;
esac
```

Comment: This won't run at least without the `;;`s